# Change the names in the column of matrix according to the other matrix

Tags: r

Let's use an example. I have a two matrix:

Matrix with names:

```
> dput(a)
structure(c("Greg", "Martin", "Hunge", "Rek", "Pred", "Singa", 
"Kreton", "Wita", "Marcus", "Sebas", "Theo", "Rox", "Plate", 
"Tret"), .Dim = c(7L, 2L))
```

Matrix with data:

```
> dput(b)
structure(c("Greg", "Hunge", "Pred", "12", "54", "11", "33", 
"44", "55", "61", "23", "68", "34", "123", "43", "22", "112", 
"35", "79", "22", "19"), .Dim = c(3L, 7L))
```

I would like to change the names in the data matrix (first column) according to the matrix `a`. So, the output should be like that:

```
> dput(c)
structure(c("Wita", "Sebas", "Rox", "12", "54", "11", "33", 
"44", "55", "61", "23", "68", "34", "123", "43", "22", "112", 
"35", "79", "22", "19"), .Dim = c(3L, 7L))
```

What's the easiest way to do that ? Remember that in `a` is more names than I need. The fucntion need to find the proper name for each row.

Comment: I don't see any pattern here, are these names just randomly replaced or am I missing something?

Comment: If you load `a` you can see that "Greg" and "Singa" are in the same row in that matrix and same goes for other names. I want to replace the names from the first column of `a` with names from second column in `a`.

Comment: I think you have either mis-specified the structure a or the pattern is not clear. It seems to be that you are substituting the ith element of as.vector(a) with the (i+5)th one, but not in the one in the next column. The function match should do what you need (e.g. if your matrix a was such that you substitute the first column with the second one, then you would use a[,2][match(b[,1], a[,1])] to substitute the first column of b)

Comment: Sorry, my bad... I wrote it wrong... Will edit soon.

Comment: @ShaxiLiver - No its looking different then what you are claiming..

Comment: Already edited it. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: And what did you tried? Subseting the vector and then replace the column doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match()` for this:

```
a <- structure(c("Greg", "Martin", "Hunge", "Rek", "Pred", "Singa", 
            "Kreton", "Wita", "Marcus", "Sebas", "Theo", "Rox", "Plate", 
            "Tret"), .Dim = c(7L, 2L))

b <- structure(c("Greg", "Hunge", "Pred", "12", "54", "11", "33", 
            "44", "55", "61", "23", "68", "34", "123", "43", "22", "112", 
            "35", "79", "22", "19"), .Dim = c(3L, 7L))

# copy
c <- b
c[ ,1] <- a[match(b[ ,1], a[ ,1]), 2]
c
#     [,1]    [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]  [,6]  [,7]
#[1,] "Wita"  "12" "33" "61" "34"  "22"  "79"
#[2,] "Sebas" "54" "44" "23" "123" "112" "22"
#[3,] "Rox"   "11" "55" "68" "43"  "35"  "19"
```

Comment: or `c[,1] <- a[a[,1] %in% b[,1], 2]`

Comment: I know, this is why I didn't post an alternative solution. I just wanted to add my prefferable operator for future readers. It also works a bit differently, notice the `a` and `b` order in my line compared to yours

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you...

```
d=merge(b,a,by.x=1,by.y=1)
c=as.matrix(d)
c=c[,-1]
c=c[,c(7,1:6)]
colnames(c)=NULL
```